# Why not split the data access layer into two?

Tags: domain-driven-design, data-access-layer

Everywhere I look, I noticed that both Domain Driven Design (DDD) and entity hydration approaches attempt to populate entities directly from the data layer. I disagree with such approaches. It is not because these approaches do not work because these do. Instead, I would argue that such approaches give a low level of transparency for testing purposes. I propose that at the data access layer, data is retrieved to populate dictionaries instead of the directly populating the entities themselves. There are several reasons for this:

First, there is greater flexibility. A dictionary per result set could be populated. We would decide later which entities could be populated from these result sets.

Second, less knowledge about the data layer is needed to determine where data retrival is failing. We may still write tests for verify data retrieval without having to understand anything about its associated complex domain entity factories.

There is one so-called disadvantage, performance? Going through two layers is slower than going through one? Yes, it is but the performance gain from going through a single data layer is negliable here. The reason I say this is because both the dictionaries and the entries these dictionaries would populate would be cached. So, if anything there would be a memory overhead. I think this would be worthwhile to gain the two advantages stated above.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're suggesting here or what the question is. I think this belongs in a blog post...

Comment: The question is Why not split the data access layer into two?

Comment: So what would be stored in the 'dictionary'? A property bag for each entity? I think a code example would help describe what you're suggesting but it sounds like a lot of extra work to me and I'm struggling to understand the point.

Comment: In DDD you would have repositories that acts like in memory collections of data. The repositories are on top of what ever data access layer implemented to support persistence. In these repositories you can implement a caching mechanism as well ... I too don't entirely understand where you are going ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like testing is the issue ("for testing purposes"), so I suggest you use [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) just like @tschmuck pointed out.

[As Ayende points out](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/repository-is-the-new-singleton.aspx), they might give you unnecessary lasagna code (i.e. too many layers), but they will give you flexibility. You can implement fakes/test spies yourself, mock and stub 'em, as well as use an in-memory DB such as SQLite, and the dependent class is just as happy.